# How to properly dispatch the same action twice in a single React Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to understand the best approach to a data fetching challenge I am facing with redux in my react app.

In short, I need to dispatch the same fetch (in this case, `fetchPlayerSeasonStats`) twice, and save both fetches of data. The first fetch grabs statistics for a single player (via the fetches optional 1st paramter `thisPlayerId`), and the 2nd fetch omits the paramter and fetches a much larger dataset.

What I've attempted to do below is the following:

(a) fetch `playerSeasonStats` the first time

(b) in `componentDidUpdate()`, check that the first fetch was completed (the `if` condition checking array legnths).

(c) if condition met, use state variable `thisPlayersSeasonStats` to store the original fetch of data.

(d) then, refetch the larger dataset with another dispatched action.

... other than the warning I'm receiving saying "do not update state in componentDidMount", in general I'm not sure if this approach is correct or if it is an "anti-pattern" / bad React/Redux coding style. I'd like to make sure I'm doing this right so any review of the code below (in particular the `componentDidUpdate()` function) would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
// Import React Components
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Import Fetches
import { fetchPlayerSeasonStats } from '../../../actions/...';

// Create The Component
class MyComponentHere extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            thisPlayerSeasonStats: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let thisPlayerId = this.props.playerInfo._id;
        this.props.dispatch(fetchPlayerSeasonStats(thisPlayerId, this.props.appSeason.value));
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log('prevProps: ', prevProps);
        if (this.props.appSeason !== prevProps.appSeason) { this.refetchTeamsStats(); }
        if (prevProps.playerSeasonStats.length === 0 && this.props.playerSeasonStats.length === 1) {
            this.setState({ thisPlayerSeasonStats: this.props.playerSeasonStats });
            this.props.dispatch(fetchPlayerSeasonStats(null, this.props.appSeason.value));
        }
    }

    render() {
        // Handle Initial Loading Of Data
        if (this.state.thisPlayerSeasonStats.length === 0) { return <LoadingSpinner />; }

        // The Return
        return (
            <div> Return Dont Matter For here </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
    return {
        playerSeasonStats: reduxState.playerSeasonStatsReducer.sportsData,
        loading: (reduxState.playerSeasonStatsReducer.loading),
        error1: reduxState.playerSeasonStatsReducer.error
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponentHere);
```

Comment: if you're already using redux in your app, should have a look at redux-thunk or redux-saga, for small scope `redux-thunk` is enough for you, Try to call request and process the logic all inside the `thunk` then just `dispatch` once to `reducer` with full data.

Comment: Don't read into it. It's random. I think you should consider architecturing this differently, Even though, you need two fetches it seems to be fall under the same action. You should create a meta-action that combines these two dispatches into one, then the view only has to fire one action on mount

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple.

Lets look at how [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation) works.

> Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that **return a function** instead of an action

I think this is what `fetchPlayerSeasonStats` essentially do. It returns some async function that fetch players. Redux-thunk helps dispatch it (I think you use Redux-thunk. In case of you use some other async middleware, it should work essentially the same).

So we can write action creator that will return function (as `fetchPlayerSeasonStats`) but inside will dispatch not actions but another function. So we'll have function dispatching function which will dispatch action :-)

For example

```
fetchAllPlayerStats (thisPlayerId, appSeasonValue) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchPlayerSeasonStats(thisPlayerId, appSeasonValue));
    dispatch(fetchPlayerSeasonStats(null, appSeasonValue));
}
```

Then you can use `this.props.dispatch(fetchAllPlayerStats(thisPlayerId, this.props.appSeason.value))` from `componentWillMount` to fetch all data at once.

Tip. Current implementation of `fetchAllPlayerStats` will get all data at once. If you add async/await keywords you'll get firstly data for a single player and then larger data set. Modified version will look like

```
fetchAllPlayerStats (thisPlayerId, appSeasonValue) => async dispatch => {
    await dispatch(fetchPlayerSeasonStats(thisPlayerId, appSeasonValue));
    await dispatch(fetchPlayerSeasonStats(null, appSeasonValue));
}
```

Here is simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56593925-tq24k) to showcase logic

Comment: I've already got redux thunk installed on my application. Yes `fetchPlayerSeasonStats` is an sync function to fetch that data.

Comment: Most probably yes, both datasets will be loaded to the same place. I suggest to create 2 different actions: like `FETCH_PLAYER_STATS` and `FETCH_ALL_PLAYERS_STATS`. First action will be dispatched by `fetchPlayerSeasonStats`, second - by `fetchAllPlayersSeasonStats` (yes, you'll need additional action creator). And in reducer process these two actions separately.